# (sml) I'm going to make a function that prints a string tree beautifully in Lisp notation

Tags: sml

In fact, I don't know exactly what "lisp notation" means.
So I tried to make it as similar to the list format as possible, but I can't express it like an example because () or (,) looks the same.
How can I represent a list like the example?

---

- my sml code:

  datatype 'a Tree = null | Tree  of 'a Tree list | leaf of 'a;

  fun prettyprint(null) = [] | prettyprint(leaf(v)) = [v] | prettyprint(Tree(h::t)) = prettyprint(h) @ prettyprint(Tree(t)) | prettyprint(Tree([])) = []

  val ex = Tree [leaf( 2 , 3 ,( 1 , 3 ), 4 ,( ( 3 ) ), 7 )];

---

- Examples to represent:

  val it = " ( 2 3 ( 1 3 ) 4 ( ( 3 ) ) 7 ) " : string

---

Comment: Did you try [this website](https://www.google.com/search?q=lisp+notation)? It's quite useful.

Comment: Well, I use Google a lot, but I haven't seen anything that can help me get the results I want. I don't want the prefix to add up, I want to show you the elements I visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be your exact solution. But Lisp is a family of programming languages with a long history and a distinctive, fully parenthesized prefix notation.

When representing source code in Lisp, the first element of an expression is commonly an operator or function name and any remaining elements are treated as arguments. This is called "prefix notation" or "Polish notation". As an example, the Boolean expression written `4 == (2 + 2)` in **C**, is represented as `(= 4 (+ 2 2)`) in **Lisp**'s prefix notation.

You can find many prefix (or preorder) algorithm in the net and implement it based your program language.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm learning sml language now, so I'm not good at it.
But I wonder if the lisp language and ML language are the same.
Also, the book I have now feels like explaining the concept of sml in words, not code, so I understand the concept, but it is difficult to implement it in code. Are there any sites or books where I can learn many of these example codes?

Comment: Lisp and ML are not same. I think both of them follow one style (i.e. functional programming, not imperative). However you can find many example on the net. I suggest start from hello world and then when you could, try implement above algorithm. see [this](https://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/introml/) for start